# Java EE 6 injection to create different strategies

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

Say that I have class Controller with property strategy of type IStrategy. In Spring, I can create different instances of Controller and inject different strategy implementations by defining beans in xml configuration file as shown below:

```
<bean id="strategyAController" class="com.test.Controller"> 
    <property name="strategy" ref="strategyAImpl">
</bean>

<bean id="strategyBController" class="com.test.Controller"> 
    <property name="strategy" ref="strategyBImpl">
</bean>

<bean id="strategycController" class="com.test.Controller"> 
    <property name="strategy" ref="strategycImpl">
</bean>
```

I can then reference these beans using @Autowired and @Qualifier("strategyAController"), etc. What is the equivalent way of doing this in Java EE 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny you should ask! Gavin King, who designed Java EE 6 CDI, got into a nasty fight with someone on exactly the same problem.

http://www.tsolak.com/?p=59

The Spring code, of course, looks awfully like Java. We can do that in java - create some variables, set some properties, no biggie. I am curious, in your perticular application, what's the drawback of doing it in plain Java? What's the specific benefit you get from Spring for these beans?

Comment: Wow. Not to start a mini-flame war here, but Gavin is wrong there. Or at least he is being defensive about a case where Spring's injection is clearly more flexible than EE.

Comment: thanks for the link. 

>>what's the drawback of doing it in plain Java? 
it's much easier to do it in xml. XML files w/ different configurations can be included/excluded during build process. 

>>What's the specific benefit you get from Spring for these beans?
Ease to create different bean instances w/ different dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In CDI you can use Qualifer to identify the different instances and producer methods to provide that instances.

```
public class  ControllerFactory {

  @Produces
  @StrategyA
  public Controller createControllerA {
      return new Controller(configA);
  }

  @Produces
  @StrategyB
  public Controller createControllerB {
      return new Controller(configB);
  }
}

@StrategyB
@Inject
Controller howToAccessIt;
```

If you do not like to create a new `StrategyA/B/C` Annotation for each strategy, you could use one Annotation with an Field (for example an Enum) that identify the strategy. So that you can write: `@Strategy(StratType.A)`.

Then you can use the `InjectionPoint` in your producer method, so that you can create the instance depending on the annotation in a generic way, instead of writing a new producer method for each Strategy:

```
@Produces
//must add a Annotation to clarify that this producer produces for all Strategies!
public Controller createController(InjetionPoint ip) {
    Annotated annotated = ip.getAnnotated(); 
    if (annotated.isAnnotationPresent(Strategy.class)) {
       Strategy stragtegyAnnotation = (Strategy) annotated.getAnnotation(Strategy.class);
       switch(stragtegyAnnotation.value) {
          case A: return new Controller(configA);
          ...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably the simplest solution is with `@Named()` qualifiers and producer fields.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not really familiar with EE6 annotations, but I solved a similar issue using pure Spring annotations in a question that I [asked and then answered myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696802/how-can-i-qualify-an-autowired-property-with-a-variable-from-a-config-file-using). It's not quite the same thing because it only creates once instance, but with all of the different dependencies injected into a Map. Basically, it will allow to switch implementations based on a config flag, but not instantiate all of them at once.

Comment: thanks for your comment - your problem and solution are interesting (my problem is little different though)